# std::cin , unwanted behaviour. and how can I fix this?

Tags: c++, iostream, cin, istream

I tried to play with some code to test overloading functions. The overloading part went well, however, I learned something about std::cin that made me feel stupid for not noticing it before!

```
#include <iostream>
void read (int *var){
    std::cout<<std::endl<<" input :";
    std::cin>>*var;
}
void read (float *var){
    std::cout<<std::endl<<" input :";
    std::cin>>*var;
}
void read (char *var){
    std::cout<<std::endl<<" input :";
    std::cin>>*var;
}
void read (bool *var){
    std::cout<<std::endl<<" input :";
    std::cin>>*var;
}
int main(){
    int a;
    float x;
    char c;
    bool s;
//  std::cin>>a;
//  std::cin>>x;
//  std::cin>>c;
//  std::cin>>s;
    read (&a);
    read (&x);
    read (&c);
    read (&s);
    std::cout<<a<<std::endl<<x<<std::endl<<c<<std::endl<<s<<std::endl;
    return (0);
}
```

When compiled with g++ this is what happens:

```
$ g++ test1.cpp -o test
$ ./test

 input :1.2

 input :
 input :a

 input :0
1
0.2
a
0
```

I already tried many values and added some instructions in between, but I still get the same behaviour, which is annoying if I try to read multiple values and more so if they were in different types.

**The commented text does basically the same as the 'read' functions below and has the same behaviour. I am using a function because I just wanted to do so :D**

Comment: `1.2` is not a valid integer. The `1` is read and the `.2` is left over for the next cin

Comment: "**std::cin function**", `std::cin` is NOT a function. It's a global object: [std::cin, std::wcin](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin)

Comment: The commented code does not write any prompts to `std::cout`.   But it does read from `std::cin` in the same way.   Your overloaded versions of `read()` work because I/O stream objects (like `std::cin`) have overloads of `operator>>()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a strange behaviour what really happens is when this line is executed in the read int function:

```
 std::cin>>*var;
```

it expects an integer from your keyboard buffer and when you enter this as input:

```
1.2
```

the cin object reads the first digit until the decimal point because it is the integer part and leave the remaining characters inside the buffer so variable `a` will have the value `1` and the characters `.2` will be lifted over in the buffer.

So when the read float function executes it doesn't wait for your input because there is already a floating point number inside the buffer so it reads it and stores it in the variable so it's value becomes `0.2`.

Comment: I kind of knew it was storing the part that it didn't read somewhere, but I wanted to delete it so I don't get any errors later on.

Comment: You can do so using `cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max())` but you have to include `#include <limits>`

Comment: `numeric_limits<streamsize>::max() sets the maximum number of characters to ignore. Since this is the upper limit on the size of a stream, you are effectively telling cin that there is no limit to the number of characters to ignore.`

Comment: this simply ignores the leftover part.